# How to crop text in photo in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have an image with arabic text , I wanna to crop and fit the photo to the text . for example something like this

[image]

how can I do this with matlab? 
I try to solve with regionprops function and BoundingBox property but it separate the none connected parts and considering them as separate objects but I want one object

Comment: Can you show us your current code? Seems you only need to merge (http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/7844-geom2d/content/geom2d/geom2d/mergeBoxes.m) the bounding boxes to achieve the intended result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you already got the bounding boxes for each individual object, you can deduce the bounding box that gets them all. However, just getting the indices to the coners will be much simpler and efficient. Supposing that `mask` is a logical matrix with your text:

```
xs = any (mask);
xi = find (xs, 1, "first");
xf = finf (xs, 1, "last");
```

Then do the same for the y axis:

```
ys = any (mask, 2);
yi = find (ys, 1, "first");
yf = finf (ys, 1, "last");
```

The bounding box for your text will be:

```
text = mask(yi:yf, xi:xf);
```

Answer (score 1):

When you provide `regionprops` with a labeling of type `logical` it runs `belabel`behind the scene, thus seperating it into its connected components. If you convert your `BW` mask to `uint8` or any other type `regionprops` will treat it a single component providing you with the desired bounding box.